# Can we bind any events on div dynamic height change in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a div where height is changed dynamically. Can we capture the div's height in jquery?

```
$('#div').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
  alert('changed');
});
```

I have tried binding events but none of the events getting fired. I have also tried binding custom events. Didnt help me. No plugins please.

Comment: What changes the height of the div? Is it the user resizing the browser window, or is the height changed programattically? (If the latter, is it *your* code that changes it, or some third-party library/plugin?)

Comment: There are child divs inside the main div. So according to the child windows hieght the main div gets adjusted. Now on top of the main div there is a map which needs to be resized. So i have to capture the height of the main div in the code. So how can I handle the same.